# convergence of martingale

Tags: probability, martingales

I found an old exam in stochastic Analysis but without a solution. Here is the exercise:
Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = k) = 2^{-k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $Z_{0} = 1$ and 
\begin{equation}
Z_{n} = 3Z_{n-1}/2^{X_{n}},~~n\geq1.
\end{equation}

(a) Show that $(Z_{n})_{n\geq0}$ is a martingal with respect to the filtration $\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{n}))_{n\geq0}$

(b) Show $Z_{n} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely

I have done part (a). But how can I Show part (b)?

Comment: Please refrain from re-posting your questions. Which results on the convergence of martingales do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By iteration we get $Z_n=\frac {3^{n}} {2^{S_n}}$ for $n \geq 2%+$ where $S_n=X_2+X_3+...+X_n$. By Strong Law $Z_n^{1/n} \to \frac 3 {2^{EX_1}}=3/4$ almost surely. This implies that $Z_n \to 0$ a.s..

Comment: thanks! how would you Show that $(Z_{n})$ is a Martingale. First I must Show that $\mathbb{E}(Z_{n}) < \infty$ for all $n$. How can I Show this

Comment: $E\frac 1 {2^{X_i}} =\sum \frac 1 {2^{k}}  \frac 1 {2^{k}}=\frac  1 3$ so from the formula for $Z_n$ in my answer $EZ_n=\frac {3^{n}} {(\frac 1 3 )^{n}}=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I have Problem to Show that $\mathbb{E}(X_{1}) = 2$. I have $\mathbb{E}(X_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\geq i)$. Now what is$\mathbb{P}(X_{i} \geq i)$? Is this equal to $\frac{1}{2^{i}}$?

Comment: $P\{X_i \geq i\}=\frac 1 {2^{i-1}}$.